# how to fix this error ? ionic 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

> (node:10624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Source path does
>   not exist: google-services.json
>       at updatePathInternal (D:\ion\Event\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\FileUpdater.js:145:19)
>       at D:\ion\Event\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\FileUpdater.js:223:19
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object.updatePaths (D:\ion\Event\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\FileUpdater.js:221:33)
>       at updateFileResources (D:\ion\Event\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:431:17)
>       at D:\ion\Event\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:51:9
>       at _fulfilled (D:\ion\Event\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
>       at D:\ion\Event\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\ion\Event\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
>       at D:\ion\Event\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
>   (node:10624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:10624) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

---

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm --save
>   Plugin "cordova-plugin-fcm" already installed on android.

Adding cordova-plugin-fcm to package.json

Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-fcm" to config.xml

```
(node:11704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cordova-plugin-fcm: You have installed platform android but file 'google-services.json' was not found in your Cordova project root folder.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ion\Event\plugins\cordova-plugin-fcm\scripts\fcm_config_files_process.js:84:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at runScriptViaModuleLoader (C:\Users\DINESH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:178:20)
    at runScript (C:\Users\DINESH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:164:16)
(node:11704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11704) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.` <platform name="android">
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" 
         target="platforms/android/app/google-services.json" />
    </platform>`
```

Comment: You are using firebase service?

Comment: No, I am not using firebase

Comment: cordova-plugin-fcm, fcm means firebase cloud messaging so you need to download google-service.json and need to put in root of project

Comment: ok, another error , TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer

Comment: ok frnd I fixed this problem. Now working fine